# Hash syntax for gem options

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to implement recaptcha using the https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/ gem. It says in the documentation that the :display option on recaptcha_tags is used like this:

> Takes a hash containing the theme and tabindex options per the API.
>   (default nil), options: 'red', 'white', 'blackglass', 'clean',
>   'custom'

My code looks like this

```
<%= recaptcha_tags:, display => ["clean"] %>
```

This isn't working however, how should it look?

Comment: For future reference, even though this one is trivial, saying something "isn't working" is not sufficient. Include the precise error message(s) you receive.

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this:

```
recaptcha_tags display: [ "clean" ]
```

That's the equivalent of the Ruby 1.8 style:

```
recaptcha_tags :display => [ "clean" ]
```

In both cases the `:display` option is specified, just that in Ruby 1.9+ it's more easily expressed as `display: value`.

Comment: I'm now getting can't convert Symbol into Integer, any ideas?

Comment: It's not clear what the `display` options are supposed to be, but it says it's a hash and not an array. In that case you'd need to adjust that. Maybe `{ theme: 'clean' }`?